# Integrate Ad Gallery and Colorbox

Tags: colorbox

I have an Ad Gallery plugin (http://adgallery.codeplex.com/documentation) and want when I click on the image it opens colorbox plugin.
There is this code snippet provided by Ad gallery which integrates with Fancybox:

```
$(".ad-gallery").on("click", ".ad-image", function() {
     $.fancybox.open({
           href : $(this).find("img").attr("src"),
           closeBtn: false,
           closeClick : true,
           openEffect : 'elastic',
           openSpeed : 150,
           closeEffect : 'elastic',
           closeSpeed : 150,
           helpers : {
           overlay : null
           }
           });
        });
```

How should the colorbox code be to integrate with Ad Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

With `colorbox` it is almost the same:

```
$('.ad-gallery').on('click', '.ad-image', function () {
    $.colorbox({
        href: $(this).find('img').attr('src'),
        title: $(this).find('.ad-image-description').text()
    });
});
```